# I get a Not found error when I deploy ASP.NET CORE 2.0 WebApi to IIS under Default Website

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

[image][image][image: Scrrenshot of my IIS]

It works well with the label "2" outside of default website but it does run inside the default website

Comment: What are app pool settings when running the .net core app as a sub-application under "Default website"?

Comment: The  app pool is DefaultAppPool

Comment: OK for running .NET Core app you need an app pool with .NET CLR Version set to `No Managed Code` so either create a new app pool or for testing assign the same app pool you had for label 2 app

Comment: Thanks for your response. but i did that and it's still the same error

Comment: What does your Default Website maps to? Is it another application with its own web.config?

Comment: No. Just the default website that ships with IIS. I just want to be able to use the default port. instead of deploying on another port

Comment: Is there any redirect to domain root when you initially load the .net core app? I mean when you try to load `http://localhost/iaudit_api_net_core/` does it show 404 on that url? Update question with error screenshot showing browser url if possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172600/discussion-between-bakare-isaac-omotayo-and-mohsin-mehmood).

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

Install the hosting bundle again, and then publish from Visual Studio again.

If that doesn’t fix it, go to the publish output folder and run `dotnet run <YourWebDll>.DLL`

Comment: `dotnet run` returns :
`Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in <path to my app>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\publish, or pass the path to the project using --project.`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already install either ***[SDK or Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)*** in web server.

Then, you need to install ***[ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1)*** in web server. 
Here is the [download link](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting).

**Trouble Shooting**

If it still doesn't work, open a command prompt. Navigate to the web application folder and type `dotnet YOUR_APP.dll`. You should see something like this -

```
C:\APIs> dotnet YOUR_APP.dll
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\APIs
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started: Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

It means your application can run in the web server without IIS. Then you need to trouble shoot in IIS or some other things.

Comment: so it ran fine when i did that. Its running on IIS its just not running under default Website, where i want it to use port 80

Answer (score 1):

In my case, moving the published application (to publish do : `dotnet publish -c Debug` from the project folder) inside the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<site>` path fixed the problem.

It would not work from inside my project folder, for some reason.
The weird thing is that the users configured on IIS had access on the folder when it was failing. So, go figure...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `~` or `..` my login page path `~/Account/Login` instead `/Account/Login`.
Now I can use Default Web Site/My Site.