# Deploying ASP.NET Core

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I've built the simplest ASP.NET Core website to try and deploy. It isn't even returning an error.

IIS will return a .HTM page so that feels OK

I've installed .Net Core Windows Server hosting

I used a folder deploy and put the folder under c:\inetpub\wwwroot

I set the Application Pool .Net v4 [I've also tried No Managed Code]

I added the application to the Default website

What else?

UPDATE: Thanks to Win I found this out:

Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (razortest.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-linux-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-osx-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x86.xml

So I'm either missing a file or pointing to the wrong one - but in VStudio or on the server????

Comment: Could you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50707255/296861)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

1. You need to publish your website and then point IIS website to the published folder
2. Application pool must be set to `No Managed code`
3. Application Pool identity user `IIS AppPool\{AppPoolName}` must have read permissions on the published website folder

Comment: Between Mohsin & Win it's running!