# Can't publish ASP.NET Core anything to IIS Host

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

First I will like to disclose that this is my first attempt at publishing a .net core app to a live server. Everything I have done on the past has been on a local Host Server.

The problem I am having is that I can't get any kind of application even the temple created in VS2017 V15.7.2 to return anything other than 500 server error. I can't even get it to produce log files so I can try to figure out what is going on.

Here is my web.config file from the published server.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BareBones.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I can connect via FTP and see all of the files but, that is about it. Of course everything works great locally.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to install the hosting bundle on the server, did you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807171/deploying-asp-net-core)

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4 No. Not all the files are there yet.

Comment: Thanks for the direction guys. I am looking into how the server is set up.